# Patterns for adding inferred relationships to a neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

We are importing a large amount of data into a Neo4J database using the batch insertion API . The database will be used to power a readonly API (embedded server).

The data we are importing is a very close copy of the domain concepts/entities that are held in the existing database schema. We are exploiting these relationships to find additional relationships in the data and drive additional features on our website.

For example, if we had the following: person-[:reads]->book-[:writtenBy]->person , we might decide that this implies an additional relationship person-[:isAFanOf]->person. This makes our code a little more evident (as we talk about the "is fan of" relationship), and many of our queries and traversals a lot more performant as there is no need to hop across two entities.

Where would be the best place to do this? We came up with a number of suggestions:

- In the batch insert code, after all the relevant entities have been imported.
- In a process that 'spiders' the network, looking for users to add inferred relationships, adding these and then scheduling their neighbours for the same.
- At read time in the API - not idea as this could make quite a long initial load time for the user consuming the data

Another complication is that the database will be updated every 24 hours with newly created data so we need something that helps us in our full and our partial import case.

Examples/experience very much welcome.

Comment: What can be done to insert inferred relationships like [:isAFanOf] on real-time data; I mean the moment the relationship is being written person-[:reads]->book-[:writtenBy]->person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you required to use Cypher? If not, since you have 60 million nodes, the cypher query listed by `tstorms` looks nice and works fine, but it might be tough as it would do a transaction around all those, which could lead to big memory usage.

You could use the Java API(I'm assuming you're using Java) to do this manually.

```
        RelationshipType readsRelationshipType = DynamicRelationshipType.withName("reads");
        RelationshipType writtenByRelationshipType = DynamicRelationshipType.withName("writtenBy");
        RelationshipType isAFanOfRelationshipType = DynamicRelationshipType.withName("isAFanOf");
        int counter = 0;
        Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
        try {
            for (Node reader : GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllNodes()) {
                for (Relationship reads : reader.getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING, readsRelationshipType)) {
                    Node book = reads.getOtherNode(reader);
                    for (Relationship writtenBy : book.getRelationships(Direction.OUTGOING, writtenByRelationshipType)) {
                        Node author = reads.getOtherNode(book);
                        try {
                            reader.createRelationshipTo(author, isAFanOfRelationshipType);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: Something for exception
                        }
                    }
                }
                counter++;
                if (counter % 100000 == 0) {
                    tx.success();
                    tx.finish();
                    tx = db.beginTx();
                }
            }
            tx.success();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.failure();
        } finally {
            tx.finish();
        }
    }
```

This code assumes error handling, and number of transactions, but you can adjust those as you need.

Comment: That looks good - I might consider using a cypher query with parameter bindings to make it a little more readable. GlobalGraphOperations is a new one on me - that does look like it's going to work well spanning across my large graph. It's a shame the same approach doesn't work with indexes (to my knowledge anyway).

Comment: Well it *could*, however if I understand your use case, you need to scan all nodes to find these relationships. Otherwise, you would index all "reader" type nodes, and then just use an index to get them all back.

Comment: I had a look at the code underlying the global stuff and it seems to me they use the node IDs to lazily walk through all the nodes. I don't think that lucene would let you do this - yes you can lazily walk through the nodes once you have the results from lucene, but you still have to wait for node:READER("id:*") to return - that's my experience from running cypher queries that start from there anyway - would love to be wrong though!

Comment: If your `READER` count is much lower than your total node count, it would be beneficial. Lucene is fast, so you shouldn't worry about that being a bottleneck. Lucene returns an iterator, so you would just traverse that. The benefit here is that you are going to be doing your match against known matches, vs having to check for everything.

Comment: OK you are right - regular iteration thru lucene should be fast enough (I can try both). My experience of lucene is when we have to do a whole lot of random index lookups during insertion of relationships in our batch process. Then it's definitely the weakest link!

Comment: @Nicholas What can be done to insert inferred relationships like [:isAFanOf] on real-time data; I mean the moment the relationship is being written person-[:reads]->book-[:writtenBy]->person?

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do it right after the import. The following Cypher statement should do the trick:

```
START p=node(*)
MATCH p-[:reads]->book-[:writtenBy]->p2
CREATE p-[:isAFanOf]->p2
```

Comment: We have imported around about 60 million nodes (18 mill of which will have the relationship). Would this not crawl? I will test it though as that seems an easier approach than what I have been exploring.

Comment: It will take some time for sure, but as this seems to be a single batch insert, I hoping slow perfomance doesn't matter that much.

Comment: We don't mind the performance being slow within reason (the whole existing import we are happy with being around 10 hours) - my concern is just with writing so many millions of relationships in one transaction. That's a long time to wait if it fails.

Comment: True, maybe you can try this on a subset of your data.

Comment: @tstorms What can be done to insert inferred relationships like [:isAFanOf] on real-time data; I mean the moment the relationship is being written person-[:reads]->book-[:writtenBy]->person?

Comment: MATCH (p1)-[:reads]->(:book)-[:writtenBy]->(p2)
CREATE (p1)-[:isAFanOf]->(p2)                  Try this; START command is going to be depricated in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query @tstorms proposed will not work in a reasonable amount of time for 60 million nodes.

If you really want to do it, there are some improvements you can do on @tstorms solution:

- use indexes for start entities (for instance person in your case) and start the queries from those ones.
- you mentioned the fact that you have to do this operation incrementally, so you probably need to keep indexes for the last batch operation so you would have to iterate on already processed nodes.

I personally wouldn't do it unless it's really necessary: for performance issue I'd wait and see before optimizing upfront, and for query simplification your can use named paths in cypher (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-match.html#match-named-path) or user defined steps in Gremlin (https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/User-Defined-Steps)

Comment: I wouldn't just do it for performance (though on my small tests, the saving is pretty good). I think the sweet spot for graph databases for the kind of analysis my team are doing is the ability to infer concepts from existing relationships. This is what the "isFanOf" thing lets us do. We could just leave those concepts as implicits - something we have to define every time we run a query, or we could have them explicitly in our data model for all to see. Right now I am favouring the latter - which is why I am interested in putting them in the data.

Comment: Also, yeah we do have indexes with all our 'person' elements in. It's 18 million nodes though so I think reading from lucene is going to still be an intensive operation - depending on how lazy the lucene lookups are.